# Xcode5 - iOS6 SDK - UDID API Error

Tags: ios6, udid, xcode5

I've recently updated my Xcode to Xcode5 GM. I've noticed that this deleted my iOS6 SDK, so I've manually copied it over into Developer/SDKs. Xcode recognizes this SDK just fine. However, when I try to compile my application with this, it throws an compiler error when I attempt to retrieve the UDID of a device.

Does anyone know why this is happening ? Shouldn't the UDID API still be available in the iOS6 SDK?

Thanks, 
Teja

Comment: The UDID has been deprecated. Technically it was deprecated in iOS6 but it has been completely removed. I believe it has been removed for security reasons.

Comment: Even if access to the UDID was still available, any call to it would cause your app to be automatically rejected at submission

Comment: Here is the Apple documentation for it https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/uniqueIdentifier (It was deprecated in iOS5 not 6)

Comment: Yes, I understand that it was deprecated. But I expect a warning (which Xcode 4.6.3 was doing) and not an error.

We use enterprise distribution to distribute it, so the App Store part is not a problem.

Comment: The reason it has been completely removed is for security reasons so they are legally obligated to remove it.

Comment: Do you have your project's deployment target still set to iOS 6?  Even if you're using iOS 6 SDK, if your deployment target is iOS 7, then UDID calls will fail due to their removal.  Further, if you install the app on an iOS 7 device, even if built properly, you'd likely get undefined/improper behavior (have you tried installing the old app on an updated device to make sure things still work?)

Comment: Yes .. building with iOS 6.1 SDK, deployment target set to 5.0. My iPad is running iOS6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be working fine in the official release of Xcode downloaded from the App store.

Answer (score 1):

The `UDID` has been deprecated. It was deprecated in `iOS 5, [Official Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/uniqueIdentifier)

```
 uniqueIdentifier

 An alphanumeric string unique to each device based on various hardware details. (read-only) 
 (Deprecated in iOS 5.0. Use the identifierForVendor property of this class or the 
 advertisingIdentifier property of the ASIdentifierManager class instead, as appropriate, or use 
 the UUID method of the NSUUID class to create a UUID and write it to the user defaults database.)

 @property(nonatomic, readonly, retain) NSString *uniqueIdentifier
```

(Above taken from Apple documentation.)

Noted by `bengoesboom` even if it was still available your app would be automatically rejected as soon as you submitted to Apple for review. This is probably the reason why it has been completely removed.

Comment: Like I mentioned above, we use enterprise distribution to distribute our app, so the App Store rejection isn't a problem..

Xcode 4.6.3 was doing the right thing and throwing a warning while Xcode5 just throws an error?

Comment: Just use the `uniqueIdentifier` instead https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/identifierForVendor it's not a huge issue to change over.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do: The following statement throws an error using iOS6 SDK: `udid = [UIDevice currentDevice].uniqueIdentifier;`

Comment: I'm not sure but this might still work https://github.com/ylechelle/OpenUDID (Don't hold me to it though)

Comment: Sorry my apologies I meant `identifierForVendor` not `uniqueIdentifier`

Comment: `NSString *uuid = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString];`